# Binary Tree with negative values

Tags: data-structures

I was solving a data structure problem and I came across a Binary Tree problem:

Find the maximum node in a binary tree, return the node.
Given the following BST

```
    1
   /   \
 -5     2
 / \   /  \
0   3 -4  -5
```

I thought that in a Binary Tree, every node's key is greater than all keys in its left sub-tree, and less than all keys in its right sub-tree.

Can a Binary Tree be unsorted ?

Comment: You might be confusing Binary Tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) with Binary search tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) or Binary heap (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). Binary tree is just a tree with up to two children at each node, nothing about actual contents.

Comment: A simple Binary Tree has no such relation among root , its left child and right child, but a Binary Search Tree has. With the above binary  tree you can do traversal and keep track of max element  while traversing, this takes `O(n)` time complexity.(`n` is the  number of nodes in the binary tree)

Answer (score 0):

A [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) is supposed to be sorted and ordered.

But a binary tree can be unsorted like the one you have shown. Binary search tree is a type of binary tree which happened to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that in a Binary Tree, every node's key is greater than all
>   keys in its left sub-tree, and less than all keys in its right
>   sub-tree.

That's property of Binary *Search* Tree.

Binary tree can be unsorted, but it isn't suitable for lookup (it doesn't have log(n) complexity).